# JSTL EL - Where is it getting value?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jstl, el

I have a controller which has the following code snippet

```
...
model.addAttribute("parade", "Parade1");
...
session.setAttribute("parade", "Parade2");
```

But when I access it using `${parade}` it gives me `Parade1`. I want to access the other one from the session. How can I do this?

Comment: EL will look up in these orders: page request session application.

Comment: Thanks that's informative.

Comment: @HiwayChe Does that mean that `Model` lives in the `page` scope?

Comment: what is your `model`?

Comment: `org.springframework.ui.Model` passed to the method annotated with `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: maybe `model` lives in `request` scope, you can test by printing `${pageScope.parade}` and `${requestScope.parade}` to see which one it lives in, I am not sure.

Comment: Yes you're right it lives in the request scope thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
${sessionScope.parade}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's quick. Sorry got no time doing my own search to a seemingly simple problem because I'm chasing time.